# TinyMCE 4.0: specifying buttons to display

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

Maybe I'm just clueless, but in looking through the documentation for TinyMCE 4.0 I can't seem to find information how how to specify which editor buttons to display. The `theme_advanced_buttons[n]` argument that works fine in TinyMCE 3 doesn't appear to be supported in version 4, and I can't find information on the replacement argument. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

How about the `theme_advanced_disable` option ([link](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3atheme_advanced_disable))?

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        theme_advanced_disable : "bold,italic"
});
```

Comment: Can you put this in the context of WordPress Code?